# Como pegar valor de um campo no SQL usando C#?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, ado.net

A ideia é que eu insira dados referente a mesma pessoa dentro do SQL, porém em Entidades diferentes, contextualizando:

Tenho a tabela `Pessoa`:

```
create table Pessoa(
ID_Pessoa int primary key identity (1,1),
Nome_Pessoa varchar(50),
CPF_Pessoa varchar(15),
Categoria(50)
);
```

e tenho a tabela `Prestador_Servico`:

```
create table Prestador_Servico(
ID_Prestador int primary key identity (1,1),
ID_Pessoa int foreign key references Pessoa(ID_Pessoa),
...
);
```

Dentro da minha aplicação eu tenho uma `int fk`, depois de inserir os dados de **Pessoa**, como eu devo proceder para "pegar" a chave primária dessa tabela para definir a *foreign key* da tabela `Prestador_Servico`?

Gostaria de algo equivalente a isto:

```
obj.Nome = "Daniel";
obj.CPF = "12345"; 
obj.Classe = "PRESTADOR_SERVICO";

SqlDataSource1.InsertCommand = "insert into Pessoa values (obj.Nome,obj.CPF,obj.Classe)";
SqlDataSource1.Insert();

//Pegar PK da pessoa que acabou de ser criada, para vinculá-la ao Prestador, usando CPF como parâmetro
obj.fk = select Pessoa.ID_Pessoa where CPF = obj.CPF

SqlDataSource1.InsertCommand = "insert into Prestador_Servico values (fk, 123, ...)"
SqlDataSource1.Insert();
```

Releve os "erros" de sintaxe, fiz dessa maneira para que meu problema fosse melhor compreendido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tudo o que pode fazer de uma vez no SQL, faça. Use o [`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Algo assim:

```
SqlDataSource1.InsertCommand = @"insert into Pessoa values (@Nome, @CPF, @Classe); 
insert into Prestador_Servico values (SCOPE_IDENTITY(), 123, ...);";
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura.](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/DataBase/InsertTwoTables.cs).

Não esqueça de usar o [`Parameters`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlCommand_Parameters) para passar os valores para a *query*.

A forma que estava usando tinha vários problemas, alguns não muito fáceis de identificar.

Comment: Eu ainda precisarei da PK da tabela para outras funções, pode editar a pergunta adicionando como posso fazer isso ?

Comment: Não, porque a pergunta não fala sobre isto, o que foi demonstrado se resolve assim, se o problema é outro pode resolver assim ou de outra forma, não tem como saber sem ver.